# URL parameter looking like directory

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I have seen websites with site IDs in the URL looking like a folder.

For example: `www.example.com/detail.html/42`. The page is always the same and gets its content-ID from the URL without the typical GET parameters (`.../detail.html?id=42`).
How can i manage this with Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript frameworks e.g. [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or if you want only the routing you can use something like [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) or do it server-side

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's done server-side using URL rewriting.

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

There are different ways of doing this depending on your technology stack (server-side).

If you're building a Single Page App these use something called hashbangs, but they aren't formatted like that.

Comment: Ok, but I've seen versions with a JS stateprovider, but have no idee if its really the right thing to do with several pages. I've seen it with one page and a few tabs

Comment: That sounds like Angular to me. The address will have a format like http://www.stackoverflow.com/index.html/#/prices - this uses something called hashbangs which load content (with Javascript) based on the URL. You can do this yourself too in JS by reading `location.hash`.